# block gadgets in google apps for education

Tags: google-apps, google-gadget, google-apps-for-education

One of the schools I support want to start teaching basic web design to their students, and would like to use google sites to do so. We need to be able to block google gadgets from the sites so that there is no risk of inappropriate content being shown to the students. Previously this could be done with domain gadget directory manager but from what I understand this stopped working when https got switched on for everything. All the places I have looked predate the https change and no longer seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is an utility called [google feedserver](https://code.google.com/p/google-feedserver)

[PrivateGadgetAdministratorsGuide](https://code.google.com/p/google-feedserver/wiki/PrivateGadgetAdministratorsGuide)
describes how to tweak http/https:

> What you can do is to copy the body of XML and change http:// links to
>   .js files to https:// and then host this file somewhere.